# JSF - Barra carregando enquanto executa um método Java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Boa dia, tenho uma tela de login, e quando o usuário clica no botão Entrar, quero que fique um incone mostrando "carregando" enquanto o método java é executado.

Segue meu código xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<title >Awake - Login Administrador</title>
```

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="2"  >
                <h:outputText value="Login: "  />
                <h:inputText value="#{loginAdmController.usuarioAdm.login}"></h:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="Senha: " />
                <h:inputSecret value="#{loginAdmController.usuarioAdm.senha}" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <center>
                <p:commandButton action="#{loginAdmController.login}" update="pagLogin"   oncomplete="excluirManualDialog.hide()"   
                    value="Entrar" style=" margin-top: 10px;" />
            </center>

        </p:panel>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Adiciona isso aqui na sua página é um componente do primefaces.

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />

<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
            <h2>Aguarde...</h2>
            <img src="/img/ajaxloadingbar.gif" alt=""/>
</p:dialog>
```

você pode adquirir imagens gif aqui http://loadergenerator.com/

não esquece de alterar o src da imagem aqui

```
  <img src="/img/ajaxloadingbar.gif" alt=""/>
```

dai quando você clicar no botão vai abrir um dialog escrito aguarde...e uma imagem de um barra carregando,circulo etc...

Answer (score 3):

Além do que o washington comentou, você pode optar tbm pelo componente "p:blockUI". Ele vai travar a sua tela e exibir algo de sua preferência como uma gif de loading por exemplo.

Veja um exemplo do seu uso abaixo:

```
<p:blockUI block="form" trigger="btnSendData form:btnChanges formTable:dTable" >
    <p:graphicImage value="images/loading.gif"/> 
</p:blockUI>
```

se reparar eu passo no atributo block o id do meu form, que é o que que quero bloquear durante meu evento. Na trigger eu estou passando os componentes que ele vai ter que monitorar para executar essa ação, como por exemplo meu botão de enviar meu form "btnSendData " ou algum evento em minha tabela que esta em outro form (formTable:dTable), como load para mudar de página por exemplo.

para mais detalhes de um olhada na documentação do componente http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml